# React Admin login by token from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to implement an SSO react-admin login

Most of the react-admin examples a is simple username/password login and get token then store at storage. But for me, token will return from Auth Provider server and redirect to http://example.com/#/login?token=TOKEN, and make react-admin to parse the URL, and set token in localStorage. Then update React admin store to mark a user as "is logged in,"

but for me I failed to simulate logged in as a hook after validating token from app main js can you help me how to do   that

Comment: could you paste your code snippet here? Do you use authProvider and then the action type called `AUTH_CHECK` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround like below is works for me, but this is quite dirty solution:

```
const url = window.location;

(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("access_token") === "null" || localStorage.getItem("access_token") === "undefined") {
    localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
  }
})();

const access_token = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
    return localStorage.getItem("access_token")
  } else if (new URLSearchParams(url.search).get("access_token")) {
    return new URLSearchParams(url.search).get("access_token")
  }
}

localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token());

export const authProvider = {
  login: () => {
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
  logout: () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
      return Promise.resolve();
  },
  checkError: (status) => {
    if (status.response.status === 401 || status.response.status === 403) {
      localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
      return Promise.reject();
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
  checkAuth: () => {
    return localStorage.getItem("access_token") ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
  },
  getPermissions: () => Promise.resolve(),
};
```

There is no login method call at all, just direct setting token to the localStorage and check with checkAuth method. Maybe, sombody will give better solution.